# Keep using the same list in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm working on a F# program that reads in a file and performs a specific action depending on the event of each line.

For example if the first word in the line is create I add a element to the list, if it's delete I delete a element from the list, if modify I modify the values in the list.

Right now I'm using map which is only applying the processEventType function to each line but I need a way to keep on processing the same list.

```
let processEventType (words:string[]) myList =
    match words with 
    | [| event; var1; var2; var3 |] when event = "create" -> Map.add var2 var3 myList
    | [| event; var1; var2; |] when event = "delete" -> Map.remove "2" myList
    | _ -> failwith "Error processing event"


 let test (lines: list<string>) =
    List.map (fun line -> (processEventType(splitLine line) myList)) lines
```

Any help is much greatly appreciated as I'm new to functional programming and F#.

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Comment: If I understand this correctly his problem is that processEventType is not returning a list that can be passed back in again for reuse.

Comment: *Maybe* you are looking for `List.fold` with an initial map state like `Map.empty` in place of `List.map`. But I'm guessing wildly, since I don't know what many of the identifiers are supposed to mean. It might be useful to reformulate this question into one or more simple questions, in which the input, meaning of used values, and desired result are clear.

Comment: @Vandroiy `List.fold` was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly it was that `processEventType` was not allowing you to use the same list over and over again. If you applied an event to a list, the resulting list of that event was not used for the next event.

Since you are new to SO I have no way to look at your history to determine your knowledge base so I can't give you references and pointers to related ideas.

Basically for `processEventType` you need to return the list (`newList`) as the final statement for each of the pattern matches

```
// Signature of processEventType 
val processEventType : string * string list -> theList:string list -> string list
```

and then in the function that calls `processEventType` take that result and using a recursive function pass that back into `processEventType`.

```
    let rec processEvents commands theList =
        match commands with
        | (command::t) ->
            let newList = processEventType command theList
            processEvents t newList
        | [] -> theList
```

For this answer I will use `let rec` when other people correctly use functions like `List.map` that can do it just the same; it's just a personal preference with doing a first cut. I could also refactor a lot of it down using `|>` but left it un-factored in case you wanted to insert `printfn` to see what was happening, or follow along with a debugger.

The code is much larger than what you had because using `F# immutable list` allows me to pass the result around as noted, as such I did more massaging of the input and added some functions to process the data as list.

```
namespace Workspace

module main =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 

        let theList = []
        let input : string  = 
            "add 1 2 3 4" + System.Environment.NewLine +
            "delete 1 2" + System.Environment.NewLine +
            "add 1" + System.Environment.NewLine +
            "delete 4 2" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
            "modify 1 5" + System.Environment.NewLine

        let lines = input.Split([| '\n';'\r' |])
        let lines = List.ofArray lines
        let lines = List.filter  (fun (x : string) -> x.Length > 0) lines
        let commands = List.map(fun (line:string) -> line.Split([| ' ' |])) lines
        let commands = List.map(List.ofArray) commands
        let convertCommand (input : string list) : (string * string list) =
            let command = List.head input
            let values = List.tail input
            (command,values)
        let commands = List.map(convertCommand) commands
        let rec merge master items = 
            match master,items with
            | [],l | l,[] -> l
            | x::xs', y::ys' -> 
                if x = y then x :: (merge xs' ys')
                elif x < y then x :: (merge xs' items)
                else y :: (merge master ys')
        let deleteItems master items =
            let deleteItem master item =
                let rec deleteItem master item acc =
                    match master with
                    | (h::t) when h <> item ->
                        let acc = h :: acc
                        deleteItem t item acc
                    | (h::t) ->
                        deleteItem t item acc
                    | [] -> List.rev acc
                deleteItem master item []
            let rec deleteItemsInner master items =
                match items with
                | (item::t) ->
                    let master = deleteItem master item
                    deleteItemsInner master t
                | [] -> master
            deleteItemsInner master items     
        let modifyItems master v1 v2 =
            let rec modifyInner master v1 v2 acc =
                match master with
                | (h::t) when h = v1 ->
                    let acc = v2 :: acc
                    modifyInner t v1 v2 acc
                | (h::t) ->
                    let acc = h :: acc
                    modifyInner t v1 v2 acc
                | [] -> List.rev acc
            modifyInner master v1 v2 []
        let processEventType (event : (string * string list)) (theList : string list) : string list =
            let (command,eventValues) = event
            match command with
            | "add" -> 
                printfn "Adding: %A" eventValues
                let newList = merge theList eventValues
                printfn "result: %A" newList
                newList
            | "delete" ->
                printfn "Deleting: %A" eventValues
                let newList = deleteItems theList eventValues
                printfn "result: %A" newList
                newList 
            | "modify" ->
                match eventValues with
                | v1::v2::[] -> 
                    printfn "Modifying: %A %A" v1 v2
                    let newList = modifyItems theList v1 v2
                    printfn "result: %A" newList
                    newList
                | _ -> failwith "Error with modify parameters"
            | _ -> failwith "Error processing event"


        let rec processEvents commands theList =
            match commands with
            | (command::t) ->
                let newList = processEventType command theList
                processEvents t newList
            | [] -> theList

        let newList = processEvents commands theList

        printfn "theList: %A" newList

        printf "Press any key to exit: "
        System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        printfn ""

        0 // return an integer exit code
```

When run this produces the following output:

```
Adding: ["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"]
result: ["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"]
Deleting: ["1"; "2"]
result: ["3"; "4"]
Adding: ["1"]
result: ["1"; "3"; "4"]
Deleting: ["4"; "2"]
result: ["1"; "3"]
Modifying: "1" "5"
result: ["5"; "3"]
theList: ["5"; "3"]
Press any key to exit:
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't expect this kind of reply. I've decided to use `List.fold`. But this is what I meant by my question, how to recursively keep returning list from processEventType